# Shortcode not working in custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I installed a Plugin in a wordpress site which uses some shortcode (like metaslider). But when I insert the shortcode in the page it is not displayed the content of the shortcode but only the string [shortcode].
Have I to insert something in the function.php file of the theme I use? (it is a custom theme)

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using shortcode in page content or widget?

Comment: I'll use the shortcode in page content

Answer (score 0):

If only the string [shortcode] is shown instead of the actual plugin output, it seems that the output of your pages does not use the do_shortcode filter properly. Without exactly knowing what's happening, try the following:

```
function filter_content_example($content) {
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_content_example');
```

This is only a first guess. Without further investigation i could not solve that problem.